# Word for the loss of one parent

Tags: single-word-requests, slang

When one has lost both parents due to death the word *orphan* is used. This word is generally but not always used for children. It can in spoken English also be used for adults.

My question is what about the loss of one parent? Is there a word for this?

Comment: It depends completely on the region and dialect. Some places I have lived , "orphaned" could also be a motherless child with an often-absent father. or other far-worse stuff.

Comment: Are you asking about **(1)** those who who have lost one parent and are raised by the other one alone, or **(2)** those who have lost one parent, leaving open the possibility that the other parent has remarried and that the stepparent plays a role in the child's upbringing? As it turns out, that is relevant to judging the adequacy of the answers posted.

Comment: Slang? *bereaved*. If a child is in bereavement and isn't an orphan... well, it ain't for the family dog. Could be for a brother or sister, but that's not going to be my assumption.

Comment: @Mazura Bereaved can mean the loss of a dog or pet and even a partner or another loved one besides parent. It does not have to be a parent.

Answer (score 23):

[Motherless](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/motherlesS) or [fatherless](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/fatherless) are terms used to refer to a child whose mother or father has died (or does not live with them).

Comment: Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146187/discussion-on-answer-by-gio-word-for-the-loss-of-one-parent); please do not continue the discussion here.

Answer (score 16):

[Merriam-Webster has an entry](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/half-orphan) for **half-orphan**, meaning someone with only one living parent.

They say specifically a child, which would match the usual usage of "orphan" (as mentioned in the question), but it might be used of an adult sometimes, either jocularly or by extension.

This doesn't distinguish which parent is dead, but could be combined with a further explanation if it matters.

Comment: +1 You could add that "semi-orphan" is also attested.

Answer (score 5):

For completeness, it's worth mentioning that *orphan* itself is sometimes used in this way. This is indicated in its Merriam-Webster definition:

> a child deprived by death of **one or** usually both parents

[[link](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/orphan); emphasis mine]

In my experience, this usage is usually found only when translating a foreign-language word that means "a child who's lost one or both parents", or at least, in contexts where there's a salient foreign language with such a word; for example, Jewish religious discussions use *orphan* in this way [[example](https://books.google.com/books?id=f4ubEAAAQBAJ&pg=PA32&dq=orphan)] because of Hebrew *yatom*, and descriptions of French law use *orphan* in this way [[example](https://books.google.com/books?id=UChHEAAAQBAJ&pg=PT527&dq=orphan)] because of French *orphelin*.

I would *not* expect a typical English-speaker to be familiar with this usage, so I'd recommend it only in situations where the context makes it clear, or where it doesn't matter if some readers misunderstand it.

Comment: Yup...that is the answer I was waiting for...the definition has changed over the years.

Comment: @Cascabel_StandWithUkraine_ FWIW though it's not in OED; that only says both. This is one example of **many, many** differences between American English and English proper.

Comment: @Pryftan: I don't think the OED is the arbiter of "English proper". (And note that it theoretically covers all forms of English, so if it's missing a sense that's known to occur in AmE then that's a gap in the OED rather than an implicit claim by the OED that it doesn't occur in BrE.) Do you have any evidence that this use doesn't occur in BrE?

Comment: Especially if the parent is the father; in traditional gender roles, the man provides financially for his family, so someone who loses their father has lost their financial support.

Comment: @ruakh It's not the only BrE dictionary? Anyway that's hardly relevant. It's not like AmE is a good example of English proper. Noah Webster and others *mutilated* English though some things do make more sense. Did you know Webster wanted to change tongue to `tung`? Women to `wimmen`? He learnt 28 languages and felt English was too complicated so he complicated it more! Don't get me started on turtleneck, jumper or other words or other opposite meanings that only make it _more_ complicated. Even if other BrE dictionaries have it AmE is not a good baseline .. at least not in other countries.

Comment: @ruakh Now technically some _do_ have it but worded slightly different. Does OED have to be _the_ standard? Of course not - that's ridiculous! But that wasn't really my point. An example _ridiculous_ thing in AmE dictionaries: _nite_ for _night_. In OED they point out it's non-standard but not in AmE dictionaries (or some?). That's absurd. Of course if they were used enough that might change (how lexicographers work) but one hopes that never does change. Another terrible example is _literally_ for _figuratively_. But language is crazy I guess. *`*shrug*`*

Answer (score 0):

It requires a bit of rewording the sentence, but the term **single-parent household** is commonly used to refer to growing up in such a scenario, though this doesn't just refer to a parent who died but also parents who divorced or were never married to begin with.  ("Orphan" doesn't necessarily require the death of both or either of the parents either, just that the child be somehow separated from them, which can happen in other ways as well.)

Comment: No, orphan is specifically for dead parents. It may be applied euphemistically for kids who were willfully abandoned by their parents as an infant, but that is considered a white lie for the sake of the kid's feelings. No more, no less

Comment: @NoName There are definitely some dictionaries that include loss of parents without requiring them to be dead, [1](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/orphan) [2](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/orphan) [3](https://www.yourdictionary.com/orphan)

Comment: Again, euphemism for the sake of the kid

Comment: @DarrelHoffman I think loss of parent is usually by death, missing or absent parent would be the other as loss implies gone forever/permanently and absent may return to visit or stay.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman but as expected these are American English dictionaries. I mean maybe the OP is okay with that but ... still. Okay Collins dictionary isn't but that's less common in the definition. So I would argue that No Name is correct. American English dictionaries also have 'nite' for 'night' and don't even mark it as non-standard so it's not like they can be relied on (that much?). Still OED does have that spelling anyway which kind of surprises me. Well that's language for you. If enough people use a word for a meaning it changes, like it or not.

Comment: At any rate, whether or not death is a required part of the definition (which seems to be a regional variation or a formal/informal usage situation), the term "single-parent household" is still a valid answer to the OP, just a slight change in wording to arrange the sentence around this phrase.